# Why does encode raise "Use of uninitialized value within @_"?

Tags: perl

With Perl v5.14.2 (provided by Debian Wheezy) this code:

```
use Encode qw(encode);
no warnings "all";

sub test_encode {
  return Encode::encode("utf8", $_[0]);
}

my $a=undef;
my $r=test_encode(substr($a,0,1));
```

produces an empty string in `$r`. I'm fine with that.

---

With Perl 5.18.2 (Ubuntu 14.04), it appears to produces this output:

> Use of uninitialized value within @_ in list assignment at
>   /usr/lib/perl/5.18/Encode.pm line 147.

(even with warnings disabled in the main scop, so apparently it's not a warning. EDIT: per answers, it's definitely a warning):

That list assignment  would be, in `Encode.pm`:

```
 146 sub encode($$;$) {
 147     my ( $name, $string, $check ) = @_;
 148     return undef unless defined $string;
 149     $string .= '';    # stringify;
```

Tweaking the code, if `undef` is passed to `encode` instead of `$_[0]`, it no longer complains. If a copy of `$_[0]` in a temp variable is passed instead of `$_[0]`, it doesn't complain too.

My question are: What would have changed in Perl between these versions that would explain the new behavior? What exactly does Perl see inside `@_` in Encode.pm line 147 ?

---

ADDENDUM: adding `Dump($_[0]);` from `Devel::Peek` at the start of `test_encode`, it outputs:

Perl 5.14.2:

```
SV = PVLV(0x23a2c10) at 0x2340998
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
  MAGIC = 0x235f950
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_substr
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_substr(x)
  TYPE = x
  TARGOFF = 0
  TARGLEN = 0
  TARG = 0x235e370
  SV = PV(0x233ec20) at 0x235e370
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (PADMY,POK,pPOK)
    PV = 0x23576b0 ""\0
    CUR = 0
    LEN = 16
```

Perl 5.18.2:

```
SV = PVLV(0x25c07c0) at 0x2546cb8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
  MAGIC = 0x2567dd0
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_substr
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_substr(x)
  TYPE = x
  TARGOFF = 0
  TARGLEN = 1
  TARG = 0x256f328
  FLAGS = 0
  SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x256f328
    REFCNT = 2
    FLAGS = (PADMY)
```

Not sure what to think of that, but the `SV` part at the end differs significantly, looks like empty string versus NULL(0x0).

Comment: @toolic: but the Encode.pm that goes with 5.14 (wheezy) has `use warnings;` in it just the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `substr` that's warning.

---

`substr` warns when its first argument is undefined.

```
$ perl -we'
   my $x;
   my $y = substr($x, 0, 1);   # Line 3
'
Use of uninitialized value $x in substr at -e line 3.
```

[Since 5.16.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5160delta.html#The-substr-operator), the warning now happens when the substring operation is actually performed instead of when `substr` is called. When `substr` is used as an lvalue, the actual substring operation is performed when the a value is fetched or stored in the returned scalar.

```
$ perl -we'
   my $x;
   my $r = \substr($x, 0, 1);
   my $y = $$r;                # Line 4
'
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at -e line 4.
```

The substring operation is done then to allow the following to work:

```
$ perl -wE'$_ = "abc"; substr($_, 0, 1) = "!!!"; say'
!!!bc
```

Since the warning now happens when the substring operation is done, it's the context of the op in Encode that determines whether the warning will be visible or not.

```
$ 5.14.2t/bin/perl -e'use warnings; my $r = \substr(my $x, 0, 1); no  warnings; my $y = $$r;'
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at -e line 1.

$ 5.14.2t/bin/perl -e'no  warnings; my $r = \substr(my $x, 0, 1); use warnings; my $y = $$r;'

$ 5.22.0t/bin/perl -e'use warnings; my $r = \substr(my $x, 0, 1); no  warnings; my $y = $$r;'

$ 5.22.0t/bin/perl -e'no  warnings; my $r = \substr(my $x, 0, 1); use warnings; my $y = $$r;'
Use of uninitialized value in scalar assignment at -e line 1.
```

---

Why did the warning starting happening where the substring operation is actually perform instead of when `substr` is called? I'm guessing, but it might be to fix the following and similar problems:

```
$ perl -wE'
    my $x = "def";
    my $r = \substr($x, 0, 1);
    $x = "abc";
    say "<$$r>";
'
<a>

$ 5.14.2t/bin/perl -wE'
    my $x;
    my $r = \substr($x, 0, 1);
    $x = "abc";
    say "<$$r>";
'
Use of uninitialized value $x in substr at -e line 4.
<>

$ 5.22.0t/bin/perl -wE'
    my $x;
    my $r = \substr($x, 0, 1);
    $x = "abc";
    say "<$$r>";
'
<a>
```

---

Prefixing `substr` with `scalar` calls it as an rvalue, though that's not documented.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for        substr($_, 0, 1)' 2>&1 | grep substr
7  <@> substr[t4] sKM/3
                    ^
                   This flag causes the special lvalue behaviour.

$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for scalar substr($_, 0, 1)' 2>&1 | grep substr
7  <@> substr[t2] sK/3
```

You could also force stringification.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'1 for     "".substr($_, 0, 1)' 2>&1 | grep substr
8  <@> substr[t2] sK/3
```

Comment: So given the deferred evaluation of substr, is there a simple way the warning can be muted? (short of avoiding `substr(undef,...)` to begin with).

Comment: Not using `use warnings;` will mute the warning... But that's not what you're really asking. Read the section I just added to the bottom.

Comment: Trivia: The four operators that return assignable values: `substr`, `keys`, `vec` and `$#array`.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. If you do almost the same thing but:

```
my $a=undef;
my $b = substr($a,0,1);
my $r=test_encode($b);
```

It works fine.

Or:

```
my $r=test_encode(scalar substr($a,0,1));
```

So I think I would have to say - this has got to be to do with return values from `substr` and context.

E.g. `@_[0]` isn't undefined - `@_` is undefined.

The `Encode` module has:

```
#
# $Id: Encode.pm,v 2.75 2015/06/30 09:57:15 dankogai Exp $
#
package Encode;
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Which will be overriding your `no warnings` directive - but hiding warnings like that isn't really desirable anyway. That's been in for a while though:

```
2.18 2006/06/03 20:28:48
! bin/enc2xs
  overhauled the -C option
  - added ascii-ctrl', 'null', 'utf-8-strict' to core
  - auto-generated Encode::ConfigLocal no longer use v-string for version
  - now searches modules via File::Find so Encode/JP/Mobile is happy
! Byte/Byte.pm CN/CN.pm EBCDIC/EBCDIC.pm JP/JP.pm KR/KR.pm Symbol/Symbol.pm
  use strict added; though all they do is load XS, it's
  still better a practice
! *.pm
  use warnings added to all of them for better practices' sake.
```

So I would suggest you might be using an older version of Encode when it's working.

Comment: old Encode.pm is `$Id: Encode.pm,v 2.42 2010/12/31 22:48:10 dankogai Exp `

Comment: Hmm, I shall dig a bit deeper. I suspect we'll find this is within the `perldelta` somewhere.

Comment: Re "`@_[0]` isn't undefined - `@_` is undefined", This makes no sense; arrays can't be undefined, only empty. It's `LvTARG( $_[0] )` that's undefined.